# Why does my package not "seem to be linked"?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-mlkit

I installed React Native using Expo Go:

```
npx create-expo-app [APP NAME]
```

After this, I installed the Firebase ML Kit package:

```
npm install @react-native-ml-kit/text-recognition --save
```

Using version 0.72.5 for React Native, it should automatically link when starting the app via `npx expo start --web`, I presume.

However, when importing the package like so:

```
import TextRecognition from '@react-native-ml-kit/text-recognition';
```

I get the following error:

```
The package '@react-native-ml-kit/text-recognition' doesn't seem to be linked. Make sure: 

- You rebuilt the app after installing the package
- You are not using Expo managed workflow
```

When starting the application using `npm start web`, I get the following error:

```
Invalid project root
```

Because I need to start the app via expo. Why is the package not linking?